# conexão de mysqly com php

Tags: php, mysqli

ola,

estou estudando PHP porem eu estou com um codigo que não esta armazenando no BD, ja debuguei ele todo, os testes de erro n retornam nada, só fica em branco mas n armazena

segue codigo:

```js
<?php 
    require 'classeFornecedor.php';

    $fornecedor = new fornecedor();
    $fornecedor->nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $fornecedor->cnpj = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cnpj', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $fornecedor->cadastrarFornecedor();

?>
```

```css
<?php


class fornecedor{
    
    private $con;
    private $nome;
    private $cnpj;
    
   
    
    public function __set($atributo, $valor){
        $this->$atributo = $valor;
    }
    public function __get($atributo){
        return $this->$atributo;
    }
    
    public function cadastrarFornecedor(){
        require 'classeConexao.php';
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO('nome', 'cnpj') VALUES ('$this->nome', '$this->cnpj')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        return 'cadastro.php';
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<?php

    
   
    
$host = "localhost";
$database = "agendamento";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
   
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database);
        mysqli_select_db($conn,$database);
        
 

?>
```

Cadastro

```
<div id="menu">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Login</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="agendamento.php">Agendamento <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="cadastro.php">Cadastro</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="consulta.php">Consulta</a>

        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<header>
        <img id="imagem" alt="Conibase - do basico ao acabamento" src="logosite.png">
    </header>
    <div class="shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded" id="cadastro">
        <header>
            <h2 id="head">
            Cadastro de Fornecerdor
            </h2>
        </header>
            <form action="cadastro-int.php" method="post" >
                <input name="nome" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="fornecedor" type="text" placeholder="Nome">
                <input name="cnpj" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="cnpj" type="text" placeholder="CNPJ">
                <button type="submit" id="botao" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Cadastrar</button>
            </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Não está dando outro erro também? as váriaveis que você está atribuindo um valor, estão privadas, no caso deveria usar o __set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vi uma parte do seu código que acredito ser o motivo de não estar inserindo os dados.  Seu 'INSERT' está sem o nome da tabela.

Está assim:

```html
<?php 
  
  "INSERT INTO('nome', 'cnpj') VALUES ('$this->nome', '$this->cnpj')";

?>
```

Deveria ficar assim:

```html
<?php

  "INSERT INTO tbl_nome_da_tabela(nome, cnpj) VALUES ('$this->nome', '$this->cnpj')";

?>
```

As aspas (no nome das colunas) também não são necessárias.

Comment: FUNCIONOUUU, OBRIGADO.

Comment: Nada, brother. Coisa boba. Isso acontece comigo direto. Rs. Se a resposta te ajudou, pode marcá-la como "aceita".

Answer (score 0):

deu certo era o nome da tabela e as aspas a mais.
só mais uma duvida.
eu usei o sqli direto pra armazenar as informações, porem eu codifiquei ele numa outra versão inserindo ele em uma classe conexao(), e instanciando ela na minha classe fornecedor num __construct, porem quando ia chamar o mysqli_query pede 2 paramentros, a conexao e a query de injecao ai meu codigo ficava assim

mysqli_query($this->con->conectar(), $query);

sendo $this->con o atributo onde armazenei a instancia no meu __construct
porem ao executar ele dava esse erro:

mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\wamp64\www\Projeto\classeFornecedor.php on line 24

segue codigo

```css
<?php
require 'classeConexao.php';

class fornecedor{
    
    private $con;
    private $nome;
    private $cnpj;
    
    Public function __contruct(){
      $this->con = new conexao();
    }
     
    public function __set($atributo, $valor){
        $this->$atributo = $valor;
    }
    public function __get($atributo){
        return $this->$atributo;
    }
    
    public function cadastrarFornecedor(){
        $this->con->conectar();
        $query = "INSERT INTO fornecedor(nome, cnpj) VALUES ('$this->nome', '$this->cnpj')";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->con->conectar(), $query);
        if($result){
        return 'ok';
        }else{
          return 'error!';
        }
   
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<?php 
class conexao{
  
  
  private $host;
  private $user;
  private $pass;
  private $database;
  
  public function __construct(){
    $this->host = "localhost";
    $this->user = "root";
    $this->pass = "";
    $this->database = "agendamento";
  }
  
  public function conectar(){
  
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->database);
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
    }
}
  
?>
```

fui tentar executar ele agr de novo 
só q dessa vez eu coloquei um return na funcao conectar pra retornar a variavel com o mysqli_connect
porem obtive esse outro erro

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function conectar() on null in C:\wamp64\www\Projeto\classeFornecedor.php on line 22

Comment: Geovane, achava melhor você elaborar uma nova pergunta pra isso. Mas pelo que eu estou vendo ali, não está faltando você, ao instanciar a classe fornecedor, já passar a instancia da classe conexao como parâmetro para o construtor da classe fornecedor e ai sim pegar esse parâmetro dentro da classe fornecedor (em seu construtor) e atribuí-lo ao atributo $con ? Não sei se deu pra ser claro.